# Is there another notation for 'is not related to'?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I have been reading *Discrete Math With Applications* and it talks about sets and their relations. It uses the notation *R* to represent something as "is related to," and *R* with a strikethrough for "is not related to." I tried to look this up online but could not find any information about it or the actual notation for it. Is it called something else or is there another notation for it?

Comment: Well, if you use $x\sim y$ to denote the relation then you can use $x\not \sim y$ to indicate that $x$ is not related to $y$.

Comment: The strikethrough is used as negation for many mathematical symbols.  In MathJax you get it with \not, so \not R gives $\not R$.  I would not expect much discussion of not related to or other negations to be found.

Comment: Note that the MathJax / Tex `\not` strikethrough can be quite ugly at times, especially with relation symbols that don't have the "standard" size.

Comment: Alternatively, if you think of a relation $R$ as a collection of ordered pairs, $(a,b)\in R$ means that $a$ is related to $b$ via $R$, while $(a,b)\not \in R$ means that $a$ isn't related to $b$ via $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are talkink about binary relations.

One notation to denote that $a$ is related to $b$ is $aRb$, and if that relation does not hold to write $\lnot aRb$ or less ambiguously $\lnot(aRb)$. Striking through the $R$ and writing $a\not R b$ is not that common, and typographically, well, you name it.

Another common way to denote a generic binary relation is to write $a\sim b$ which can be negated as $a\nsim b$ or again as $\lnot(a\sim b)$.

Comment: Oh so I didn't realize that a binary relation consists of an entirely new set, I thought it was just a notation to relate them, which would be ~. Thanks! And, it was just generally specific to the book I was reading to explain an overarching concept of functions.

Comment: @Hydroniuthic . In most versions of set theory, everything is a set. A binary relation on $A$ is some (any) subset of $A\times A.$ But even set theorists prefer to write $1<2$ rather than $(1,2)\in <$.

Answer (score 0):

Other notations for this include $\overline{R}$ and $\neg R$.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)#Complement).

Comment: It would be a good comment. Isn't it?